# Redirect based on last visited website

Tags: javascript, redirect

At the moment i'm trying to make a new script that is based on the last visited website of the user. If last visited website is x, then it needs to redirect to another page.

**Example:**
User clicks on a link on my Facebook fan-page and lands on the homepage. The Javascript now needs to take an action and redirect the user to another page. But only if the user came from http://facebook.com/[fanpage]

Is it possible to create something like this in **Javascript?**

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `document.referrer` like this:

```
if ('http://facebook.com/[fanpage]' == document.referrer) {
    location.href = 'new_destination.html';
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you output the referrer, like `console.log(document.referrer);` or `alert (document.referrer);`?

Answer (score 1):

If Facebook doesn't do some kind of referrer blocking, then use `document.referrer` to get the referring page.

(It sounds like that might be something better accomplished server-side, though, in which case you would use the `Referer` [sic] header.)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on referrers sent by the browser. They can be turned off.

Why don't you pass a special parameter in your URL?

http://www.example.com/?fromFb=1